# Поиск по регулярным выражениям в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть строка следующего вида `test = 'Найти символ key_1_2 и key_1'`. У меня есть список с ключами, которые необходимо найти в строке и извлечь их позицию `list_key = ['key_1', 'key_1_2', 'key_2', 'key_2_2']`. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я в цикле закидываю `key_1` в строку он находит этот ключ в подстроке `key_1_2`  и возвращает позицию этой подстроки.

```
import re
test = 'Найти символ key_1_2 и key_1'
list_key = ['key_1', 'key_1_2', 'key_2', 'key_2_2']
for key in list_key:
    result_search = re.search(key, test)
    if result_search:
        key_position = result_search.span()[0]
        print(key, test, key_position)
```

Как можно настроить поиск регулярки, чтобы она четко находила ключи.

Comment: зависит от контекста, но например так `result_search = re.search(r'\b'+key+r'\b', test)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавляйте `\b`, чтобы проверялись границы слов

Пример:

```
import re

test = 'Найти символ key_1_2 и key_1'
print(test)

list_key = ['key_1', 'key_1_2', 'key_2', 'key_2_2']
for key in list_key:
    result_search = re.search(fr"\b{key}\b", test)
    if result_search:
        key_position = result_search.span()[0]
        print(key, key_position)
```

Результат:

```
Найти символ key_1_2 и key_1
key_1 23
key_1_2 13
```

Answer (score 3):

**Согласно сделанному замечанию в комментариях от @gil9red:**

Для решения данной задачи необходимо использовать `\b` в начале и в конце шаблона.

**Пример ниже на соответсвует поставленной задаче. Подходит для точного совпадения по всей строке**

Для точого поиска совпадения шаблона (pattern) используйте:

`^` - начало строки

`$` - конец строки

`{10}` - количество символов совпадения, здесь 10 (не используется в примерах)

Пример: `pattern = r'^key_[0-9]$'` (`'key_1'` будет попадать, а `'key_1_1'` нет)

или `pattern = r'^key_[0-9]_[0-9]$'` (наоборот, `'key_1_1'` попадает, а `'key_1'` нет)

Comment: `^` и `$` проверяют границы текста, т.е. для `^key_` нужно, чтобы текст обязательно начинался с `key_`, а автору нужно найти внутри текста

Comment: @gil9red согласен, мой косяк торопиться. Твой ответ корректен. Использовать `\b`